# ArrayAdapter filter return wrong items

Tags: android

I have problem with filtering array adapter with custom object. I owerride custom object toString() so it returns name- which I want filter. Problem is that it filer correct count of items but wrong items. E.g. I have list with items a1,a2, b1,b2. When I enter b it filter and I see a1,a2. Here is my adapter code. I guess problem is there:

```
class CustomerAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Customer> {

private LayoutInflater mInflater;
private List<Customer> customers;

public CustomerAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
        List<Customer> customers) {
    super(context, textViewResourceId, customers);
    mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    this.customers = customers;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder;

    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.customers_list_item, null);

        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.text = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.textViewCustomerName);
        holder.icon = (LinearLayout) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.linearLayoutCustomersListEdit);

        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    // Bind the data efficiently with the holder.
    holder.text.setText(customers.get(position).getCustomerName());

    return convertView;
}

static class ViewHolder {
    TextView text;
    LinearLayout icon;
}
```

}

Here is filter setup and call:

```
customerAdapter = new CustomerAdapter(this,
                R.layout.customers_list_item, repository.getCustomers());
setListAdapter(customerAdapter);

etSearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText_customers_search);
        etSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int arg1, int arg2,
                int arg3) {
            customerAdapter.getFilter().filter(s.toString());
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1,
                int arg2, int arg3) {
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
        }
    });

    getListView().setTextFilterEnabled(true);
```

Comment: I think that you should override the getFilter method to be able to change the filter behavior and make your own filtering

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
List<Customer> customers = new List<Customer>();
List<Customer> tempcustomers = new List<Customer>();
customers = repository.getCustomers();
etSearch .addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                System.out.println("onTextChanged Key presed..."+s);


            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                    int after) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                System.out.println("beforeTextChanged Key presed..."+filterText.getText());

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                System.out.println("afterTextChanged Key presed..."+filterText.getText());
                if (!etSearch .getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("")){
                    tempcustomers = new List<Customer>();
                    String text = etSearch .getText().toString();

                    for(int i=0 ;i< customers .size();i++){

                        if(customers .get(i).toUpperCase().toString().contains(text.toUpperCase())){
                            tempcustomers .add(customers .get(i));

                        }
                    }

                        }
                    customerAdapter = new CustomerAdapter(this,
                R.layout.customers_list_item,tempcustomers  );
setListAdapter(customerAdapter);

                }else{
                    customerAdapter = new CustomerAdapter(this,
                R.layout.customers_list_item,customers  );
setListAdapter(customerAdapter);

                }
            }
        });
    }
```