# Filtering a ListView using an ArrayAdapter without overriding getFilter method

Tags: android, android-listview, android-arrayadapter

In this Stackoverflow [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2718202/custom-filtering-in-android-using-arrayadapter#answer-9418457), it is indicated that filtering can be accomplished in a `ListView` without overriding the `getFilter` method of the `ArrayAdapter` and instead implementing `toString` in the `POJO` class.

I have tried implementing it, but the filtering is not working correctly. Although the `ListView` does filter, it doesn't show the correct items in the array. So, for example, if the filter matches a single row in the `array` then one item is shown in the `ListView`, but it is the wrong item that is shown. In this scenario, the first item of the array is always shown and not the item that actually matches the entered search text.

Here is the code for my `ArrayAdapter`:

```
public class TitleListingArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Title> {

    private List<Title> items;
    private Context context;

    public TitleListingArrayAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, List<Title> items) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, items);
        this.items = items;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
    {
        View view = convertView;
        if (view == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.titlelisting_single_row, null);
        }
        Title item = items.get(position);
        if (item!= null) {
            TextView titleView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title);            
            if (titleView != null) {
                titleView.setText(item.getName());
            }
            TextView yearView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.year);
            if (yearView != null) {
                yearView.setText(String.valueOf(item.getYear())+", ");
            }
            TextView genreView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.genre);
            if (genreView != null) {
                genreView.setText(item.getGenre());
            }
            TextView authorView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.author);
            if (authorView != null) {
                authorView.setText(item.getAuthor());
            }
            RatingBar ratingView = (RatingBar) view.findViewById(R.id.rating);
            if (ratingView != null) {
                ratingView.setRating(item.getRating());
            }
            ImageView iconView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.list_image);
            iconView.setImageResource(lookupResourceId(context, item.getID()));            
        }
        return view;
    }

    private int lookupResourceId(Context context, String id) {
        String resourceName =  "thumb_"+id;
        return context.getResources().getIdentifier(resourceName, "drawable", context.getPackageName());
    }
}
```

Here is the relevant section of my `Activity` code:

```
 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.listing);
    databaseHandler = new DatabaseHandler(this);
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    List<Title> titles = databaseHandler.getAllTitles();
    adapter = new TitleListingArrayAdapter(this, R.id.list, titles);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    filterText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.filter);
    filterText.addTextChangedListener(filterTextWatcher);
}

private TextWatcher filterTextWatcher = new TextWatcher() {
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {}
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        adapter.getFilter().filter(s.toString().toLowerCase());
    }
};
```

The Title `POJO` class implements toString as follows:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    String name = this.getName() == null ? "" : this.getName().toLowerCase();
    String year = this.getYear() == null ? "" : this.getYear().toString();
    String genre = this.getGenre() == null ? "" : this.getGenre().toLowerCase();
    return name + " " +year+ " "+ genre;
}
```

Does anyone have any idea why the filtering is not working correctly and how I could fix it?

Comment: Could you provide a few examples of what you expect and what you actually get?

Comment: Looking over your code: you should implement ViewHolders (watch Google's [Turbo-charge Your UI](http://www.google.com/events/io/2009/sessions/TurboChargeUiAndroidFast.html)), `toLowerCase()` is [redundant](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.1.2_r1/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.java#ArrayAdapter.ArrayFilter.performFiltering%28java.lang.CharSequence%29) so you can remove that, and I would recommend sticking with Cursors, CursorAdapters, & FilterQueryProviders while working with databases. They are much faster than converting everything to Lists.

Comment: Thanks, Sam, for the information. I have now implemented `ViewHolders` in my `ArrayAdapter` and am looking at replacing the 'ArrayAdapter` with a `CursorAdapter`. I used `ArrayAdapter` because I am new at `Android` development and the `ListView` example that I found and based my code on made use of an `ArrayAdapter`. I will research `Cursors` and `CursorAdapters`. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10704037/arrayadapter-filter-return-wrong-items) deals with exactly the same issue that I encountered. This question also gives an example of what the filtering is doing, showing the correct *number* of items by not showing the correct items in the list.

So it seems that this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2718202/custom-filtering-in-android-using-arrayadapter#answer-9418457) is wrong, despite being upvoted six times. I resolved this by not making use of the `getFilter` method of the `ArrayAdapter` at all. Rather, I create a new `ArrayAdapter` in my `TextWatcher` instance, as follows:

```
private TextWatcher filterTextWatcher = new TextWatcher() {
     public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {}
     public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}
     public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
         if (!s.toString().equals("")) {
              List<Title> filteredTitles = new ArrayList<Title>();
              for (int i=0; i<titles.size(); i++) {
                   if (titles.get(i).toString().contains(s)) {
                       filteredTitles.add(titles.get(i));                   
                   }            
              }
              adapter = new TitleListingArrayAdapter(TitleListingActivity.this, R.id.list, filteredTitles);
              listView.setAdapter(adapter);
         }
         else {
              adapter = new TitleListingArrayAdapter(TitleListingActivity.this, R.id.list, titles);
              listView.setAdapter(adapter);             
         }
    }
};
```

Note that I also moved the declaration `List<Title> titles` out of `onCreate` and made it a member variable of my `Activity` class so that it is accessible inside the `onTextChanged` method of `filterTextWatcher`.

Comment: The `R.id.list` is derived from where? I am having an issue with my Adapter: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20524417/listview-is-blank-while-using-getfilter-function

Comment: This is it mate! This is it! This is what i was looking for and now i can hopefully complete my technical assignment for an interview. Thanks a lot mate!